# Discord Collector doesn't collect DM's

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So i'm currently making my sort of application bot, however when i'm trying to use discord collector in `dms` it just doesn't work. No idea if it's not starting or just not working because of the code.
It's probably some dumb reason but I just can't figure this one out.

```
    message.author.send("hi its me u started an application")
    const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id && m.channel.type === "dm"
    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {max: 1, time: 3*60*1000 });
    collector.on('collect', m => {
        console.log(`Collected: ${m.content}`)
    })
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: does `message.channel` here refer to the DM channel or a guild channel?

Comment: It refers to a dm channel

Comment: You're actually right. Managed to fix it by just changing the `message.channel` to the dm channel